# multiple redirects with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to do this

website.com/blog/index.php -> website.com/blog

website.com/admin/archief_login.php -> website.com/admin

this works with my code.
but I want to add this:

website.com/aa -> website.com/web/index.php?init=aa

for some reason the blog gets this redirect: website.com/blog/?init=blog

what is the best way to set these different rewrites?

> RewriteEngine on Options All -Indexes
>   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}
>   ^websit.com$ [OR] RewriteCond
>   %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.website.com$
>   RewriteRule ^admin$
>   "http\:\/\/www.website.com\/admin/archief_login.php"
>   [R=301,L]
>
> RewriteRule ^blog$
>   "http\:\/\/www.website.com\/blog/index.php"
>   [R=301,L]
>
> DirectoryIndex client_login.php
>
> RewriteRule
>   ^screen-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+).html$
>   index_client.php?screen=$1
>
> RewriteRule
>   ^invoice([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+).html$
>   make_invoice.php?id=$1
>
> RewriteRule
>   ^pack-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+).html$
>   index_client.php?screen=pack_code&wwwcode=$1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the more "general" rules lower in the file so they don't match almost all of your URLs

```
RewriteRule ^(\w)$ /web/index.php?init=$1 [L, NC]
RewriteRule ^blog$ /blog/index.php [R=301,L]
```

The above will do

```
website.com/aa => website.com/web/index.php?init=aa
website.com/blog => website.com/web/index.php?init=blog
```

If you reverse the two rules you will get

```
website.com/aa => website.com/web/index.php?init=aa
website.com/blog => website.com/blog/index.php
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I only had to alter the [L, NC] to [NC] to get it working.